# How to ensure that axios encode my space to %20 and keep $ as it is?

Tags: javascript, axios, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

this is a part of my url url -

```
foo?$filter=fooNum eq '1234567'
```

when sending the axios request, axios encodes it to - `foot%24filter=fooNum+eq+%27123456%27`

Now my backend doesnt understand "+" and %24 as $. Also axios automatically eliminates the '?' which I need in the url.

Expected url should be this - `foo?$filter=fooNum%20eq%20%271234567%27`

I have tried using paramsSerializer, endcodeComponentURI, but nothing works.
I am using axios version - 1.1.3

Comment: _"my backend doesnt understand "+" and %24 as $"_... then your backend is totally broken. What are you using so I know to avoid it?

Comment: _"axios automatically eliminates the '?'"_... that was [a problem](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4999) in Axios v1.0.0 which should have been fixed in v1.1.0. IMO all the 1.x releases are broken at this time. Stick to v0.27.2 until they iron out all the bugs

Comment: my backend is actually SAP.

Comment: I think my backend is outdated. But cant change that now. Will try with  v0.27.2

Comment: @Phil Thank you so much for the advice man. It worked, I had to roll back to 0.27.2 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `paramsSerializer` is the way to go. Run each parameter key / value through [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and replace `%24` with `$`.

Make sure you use the `params` option when making your requests to take advantage of the serialiser.

```js
console.log("Axios version", axios.VERSION);

const sapClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://echo.zuplo.io/", // replace with your base URL
  paramsSerializer: {
    encode: (param) => encodeURIComponent(param).replaceAll("%24", "$"),
  },
});

sapClient
  .get("/foo", {
    params: {
      $filter: "fooNum eq '1234567'",
    },
  })
  .then(({ data: { url } }) => {
    console.log("requested URL:", url); // this just shows the requested URL
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried this method. But didnt work. Rolling back to 0.27.2 v did. Thank you so much for your guidance.

Comment: @RupaliSingh how exactly did it not work? You can clearly see in the demo above that the request query params are formatted how you want

Comment: Okay, I didnt use axios.create but directly used paramSerializer in the axios call. That might be the problem. I will try with axios.create method.

Comment: It's `paramsSerializer` ("_params"_ plural). I often make the same mistake